# Multiple database backup using pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

Is it possible to backup multiple databases with a single pg_dump command, instead of running a pg_dump command for each database

Comment: No, that's not possible. But can easily write a batch file/shell script to do that.

Comment: please share the script if you have

Comment: Depends on your operating system. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513437/how-to-backup-all-db-by-pg-dump-in-batch-file-postgres) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21433592/330315) or [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/363397.71757.qm@web31814.mail.mud.yahoo.com) or [here](https://www.commandprompt.com/blog/a_better_backup_with_postgresql_using_pg_dump/)  or [here](https://gist.github.com/matthewlehner/3091458)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is possible using the `pg_dumpall` command: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pg-dumpall.html.

From the documentation:

> Description
>
> pg_dumpall is a utility for writing out ("dumping") all PostgreSQL
>   databases of a cluster into one script file. The script file contains
>   SQL commands that can be used as input to psql to restore the
>   databases. It does this by calling pg_dump for each database in a
>   cluster. pg_dumpall also dumps global objects that are common to all
>   databases. (pg_dump does not save these objects.) This currently
>   includes information about database users and groups, tablespaces, and
>   properties such as access permissions that apply to databases as a
>   whole.
>
> Since pg_dumpall reads tables from all databases you will most likely
>   have to connect as a database superuser in order to produce a complete
>   dump. Also you will need superuser privileges to execute the saved
>   script in order to be allowed to add users and groups, and to create
>   databases.
>
> The SQL script will be written to the standard output. Use the
>   [-f|file] option or shell operators to redirect it into a file.

Comment: does not help if you want to avoid backing up few databases in the cluster

Comment: That's not necessary true as you can specify which database you want to import when using pg_restore.